# How can I dispatch based on a value of a parameter in Java?

Tags: java, python, dispatch

There is a recurring pattern when I have for example an `enum` or a `String` and I want to dispatch based on the value of that parameter:

```java
public void myMethod(String parameter) {
    if(parameter.equals(something)) {
        doSomething();
    } else if(parameter.equals(somethingElse)) {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

What is the idiomatic way to get rid of the lengthy `if` or `case` statements? I'm thinking about something like the single dispatch generic functions in python but I want to dispatch based on value not on type.

```python
@fun.register(int)
def _(arg, verbose=False):
    if verbose:
        print("Strength in numbers, eh?", end=" ")
    print(arg)

@fun.register(list)
def _(arg, verbose=False):
    if verbose:
        print("Enumerate this:")
    for i, elem in enumerate(arg):
        print(i, elem)
```

Comment: Note that single dispatch generic functions are quite different to your Java example: They dispatch on the *type* (whereas the Java code dispatches on the value), and they take inheritance and interface (ABC) implementations into account (the simplest type-dispatching Java code would use `isinstance`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that this is most common when dealing with forms (as an example) that have multiple "actions". Although this may seem overkill, a lot of times it's actually much cleaner (and in many ways, easier) to simply "register" action handlers.

```
public class Dispatcher {

    private Map<String, ActionHandler> actionHandlerMap = new HashMap<String, ActionHandler>();

    public void perform(String action) {
        ActionHandler handler = actionHandlerMap.get(action);

        if (null == handler) {
            // no handler - throw an exception?
        }

        handler.execute();
    }

    public void addActionHandler(ActionHandler handler) {
        actionHandlerMap.put(handler.getAction(), handler);
    }

}

public interface ActionHandler {

    public String getAction();
    public void execute();

}
```

It is absolutely more code, but it's extensible, clean, and allows for a better separation of concerns. It's also much more easily *testable* which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

you could use method overriding in java.. so the equivalent should be something like

```
public void doSomething(String arg) {
//do something when param is string
}

public void doSomething(List<String> arg) {
//do something else when param is a List of String
}
```

Comment: This will switch on the *type* of the parameter, not the value. It's not clear which the OP wants but I think it's the latter.

Comment: The Python feature does late binding, as opposed to the early binding of overloading. For example, the Python equivalent of `void delegate(Object a) { doSomething(a); }` does the right thing, whereas Java either calls the `Object` overload regardless of the run time type of `a` or fails because there is no such overload.

Comment: @DuncanJones Unless OP drastically misunderstands `singledispatch`, it's about the type. That's all PEP 443 dispatches on.

Comment: based on his python code snippet, it appears that the type is what he needs, but again, his java code snippet tells otherwise.

Comment: I rephrased my question. I know about overloading what I wish to do is dispatching based on value.

Comment: @AdamArold ah, got it. In that case, I am afraid you'll have to implement it yourself. don't think there's out of the box feature like that in java. See response below by Colin if you think you'll need to support multiple values besides the two in your example. If it's just two and you know that is all you'll ever need, I'd just do a if else.

Answer (score 0):

In Java enum is a class as well, so you could extextend it and use it as :

```
interface Doable {
     void doSomething();
}
enum Stuff implements Doable {
     ONE() {
        public doSomething() { System.out.println("do one");};
     },
     TWO() {
        public doSomething() { System.out.println("do two");};
     }
}
Doable s = Stuff.valueOf("ONE");
s.doSomething();
```